# Testing javascript using d3 with Karma

Tags: javascript, d3.js, karma-runner, browserify, browserify-shim

I'm trying to use `Karma` to test a simple script that uses `d3.js` to draw a chart. The script uses `browserify` to import `d3`.

```
var d3 = require('d3');
// Some code...
```

I have configured `Karma` to use `browserify` and `PhantomJS` to run tests against this file, however no matter the config it always fails with this error:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'node.getAttribute')
```

I tried using `browserify-shim` but it made no difference. Here is an excerpt of my `karma.conf.js`:

```
frameworks: ['browserify', 'mocha'],

files: [
  'src/static/js/*.js',
  'test/js/*.js'
],

preprocessors: {
  'src/static/js/*.js': ['browserify'],
  'test/js/*.js': ['browserify']
},

browserify: {
  debug: true,
  transform: ['debowerify', 'browserify-shim']
},

browsers: ['PhantomJS']
```

Any help solving this problem would be greatly appreciated. Just to clarify, the actual code works fine, it's only through `Karma` that it breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the script I was trying to test was being loaded at the end of the `HTML body` and automatically triggering a function using `d3`. When ran through `Karma` it injects the script **before** the `DOM` has loaded, which causes `d3` to fail as it was expecting a `DOM` element to exist.

The fix was to remove the function call from the script and add it at the end of my `HTML body`:

```
<body>
    <!-- HTML code -->
    <script>
        myFunction();
    </script>
</body>
```

Since `browserify` makes things awkward, you must also attach the function to the window object in order to call it from outside the script:

```
window.myFunction = function() {
    // code
}
```

This now works both in the browser and using Karma.